# Remove HTML canvas border

Tags: html, css

I'm customising my homepage http://geotheory.co.uk/ with an interactive animation, but having trouble making it feel more seemeless in the page. I want to remove the animated canvas object's border as this creates unnecessary scroll bars. I've tried various style options such as `border` and `padding` but without any luck. The animation is a [Processing script](http://geotheory.co.uk/rectangles.pde) that is then [translated](http://geotheory.co.uk/processing-1.4.1.min.js) to javascript. The index.html reads:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>geotheory.co.uk</title>
    <style>
        canvas:focus{outline:none;}
    </style>

</head>
<body  id="home" bgcolor="blue">
    <script src="processing-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <div id="canvasContainer">
    <canvas data-processing-sources="rectangles.pde"></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
```

Grateful for assistance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you've not resetted the browser default styles...So you need to reset the default styles.. Use this

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Explanation : Browser gives padding, margins to some elements, so inorder to reset them you need to use the style which I told you else you can also use CSS reset

And also use `display: block;` for `<canvas>` (As Kolink Said)

Comment: Insufficient. Solves one problem (with a shotgun) but there are two.

Comment: @Kolink Well ya I see there, why block?

Comment: By default `<canvas>` is inline, meaning it is aligned to the baseline of the text, meaning there is a little extra space underneath it, which would cause a scrollbar to appear.

Comment: Same thing applies to images, btw ;) That's why I always add `img{vertical-align:bottom}` to my CSS

Comment: @Kolink yap am aware of the images but never used canvas...so.. ;)

Answer (score 8):

Add `margin: 0;` to the `body` tag in your css, and `display: block;` to the `canvas` tag in your css.

**Example:**

```
canvas {
    display:block;
}

body {
    margin:0;
}
```