# LibGDX Remove GWT Window Padding

Tags: java, html, css, gwt, libgdx

**Context**:

I'm deploying a LibGDX GWT application to the browser.

**Problem**:

The image below shows a snapshot of the top left section of my GWT application (the big black rectangle) featuring the undesired browser padding (in the default gray color).

[image: Browser snapshot showing the undesired light gray padding]

The image below shows a snapshot of the bottom right section of my GWT application featuring the undesired browser scrollbar (as a potential result of the above padding).

[image: Browser snapshot showing the undesired browser scrollbar]

**Goal**:

Essentially, I'm trying to display my GWT application in its entirety (in a non-popout, (not browser-F11) "full screen" context that is initialized to the client browser resolution), such that the application spans the entire HTML-space (without the need for a scrollbar, without any padding, just purely the fully resolved application (while leaving the URL/bookmark section untouched)).

How can I "shift" my GWT application (the stuff in black) to the upper left corner (removing the padding)?

**Additional Information**:

- The above screenshots are taken from a 1920x1080 browser resolution.
- Running Gdx.app.log() on the platform specific code below: Width.getClientWidth() returns 1903 and Window.getClientHeight() returns 938

*HtmlLauncher.java*

```
public class HtmlLauncher extends GwtApplication {

    @Override
    public GwtApplicationConfiguration getConfig() {
        return new GwtApplicationConfiguration(Window.getClientWidth(), Window.getClientHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public ApplicationListener getApplicationListener() {
        return Engine.getInstance();
    }
}
```

*Window.class*

```
/**
   * Gets the height of the browser window's client area excluding the scroll
   * bar.
   *
   * @return the window's client height
   */
  public static int getClientHeight() {
    return Document.get().getClientHeight();
  }

  /**
   * Gets the width of the browser window's client area excluding the vertical
   * scroll bar.
   *
   * @return the window's client width
   */
  public static int getClientWidth() {
    return Document.get().getClientWidth();
  }
```

*index.html*

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
       <head>
              <title>My Game</title>
              <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
              <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
              <script src="soundmanager2-setup.js"></script>
              <script src="soundmanager2-jsmin.js"></script>
       </head>

       <body>
              <script type="text/javascript" src="html/html.nocache.js"></script>
       </body>
</html>
```

*styles.css*

```
canvas {
    cursor: default;
    outline: none;
}

body {
    background-color: #222222;
}

.superdev {
    color: rgb(37,37,37);
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(250,250,250,0.1);
    font-size: 50pt;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: rgb(83,87,93);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgb(34,34,34),
                0px 0px 0px 0px rgb(17,17,17),
                inset 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(250, 250, 250, .2),
                inset 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 0px;
}

.superdev:active {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgb(34,34,34),
                0px 0px 0px 0px rgb(17,17,17),
                inset 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(250, 250, 250, .2),
                inset 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    background-color: rgb(83,87,93);
    top: 0px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgb(250,250,250);
}

.superdev:hover {
    background-color: rgb(100,100,100);
}
```

Disclaimer: Some default values in index.html and styles.css have been messed around with through efforts of trying to figure some things out.

Comment: You could try to us FireBug or a similar tool to find out where the padding comes from.

Comment: Got it. Thanks - you've been clutch for me twice now!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14042963/1985387):

Add margin: 0; to the body tag in your css, and display: block; to the canvas tag in your css.

Example:

```
canvas {
    display:block;
}

body {
    margin:0;
}
```